# Dynamic String Input - using scanf("%as")

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read input using `scanf` and storing into `char *` [dynamically as specified by GCC manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Dynamic-String-Input), But it is giving a compile time error.

```
  char *string;
  if (scanf ("%as",&string) != 1){
    //some code
  }
  else{
   printf("%s\n", *string);
   free(string);
   //some code
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `a` modifier to *scanf* won't work if you are compiling with the `-std=c99` flag; make sure you aren't using that.

If you have at least version 2.7 of glibc, you can and should use the `m` modifier in place of `a`.

Also, it is your responsibility to free the buffer.

Comment: compiling with '-ansi' or '--std=c98' works with scanf("%as").

Comment: Some background on the `m` flag, since the GCC/glibc docs don't mention it: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2007-09/msg01342.html

Comment: To use the `a` modifier, pass -D_GNU_SOURCE to gcc, but of course better use `m`.

Comment: Confusingly, with _GNU_SOURCE defined (in the .c before any `#include`s), gcc 4.9.2 with `-std=gnu99` warns that `%a` wants a `float*`, but you're passing it a `char **`.  But the behaviour matches `%m[`.  It took me a while to remember that `%a` was a dynamic allocation conversion, because the man page doesn't mention the old GNU meaning anywhere near the other modifiers.  Even the new POSIX.1-2008 `%ms` / `%m[` only gets mentioned in a dense paragraph in with the field width stuff.  Really easy to miss. :/

Answer (score 1):

Do you have GNU extensions enabled? Standard C doesn't have `a` modifier at all.

Answer (score 1):

'Dynamic String Input' with `scanf("%as")` will work if the `-ansi` or `-std=c89` flag is enabled.
Compile using `gcc -ansi`

Or else you can use `scanf("%ms")`

Answer (score 0):

I've had limited experience with GCC, but I've never seen a `%a` modifier for `scanf`.  Have you tried replacing the `%a` with `%s` in the third line you provided?

Comment: Please refer to the link provided. FYI %c stores only 1 char. I am trying to dynamically allocate memory for storing a complete string of 0-9a-zA-z characters.

Comment: I know what `%c` does - I just missed that bit.  What happens when you use `%s` instead of `%a`?

Comment: %s will work if you already have allocated memory.
whereas %as (with a flag) allocates required memory itself to *variable which can later be freed()

Comment: @nvl - That I did not know.  Thanks for the info :)