# Why do i get segfault at the end of the application after everything's been done properly?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        unsigned char *stole;
        unsigned char pass[] = "m4ak47";
        printf("Vnesi password: \t");
        scanf("%s", stole);
        if(strncmp(stole, pass, sizeof(pass)) != 0)
        {
                printf("wrong password!\n");
                exit(0);
        }
        else
                printf("Password correct\n");
        printf("some stuf here...\n\n");
        return 0;
}
```

This program is working nice, but with one problem - if the password is correct then it DOES do the printing of 'some stuf here...' but it also shows me segmentation fault error at the end. Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unsigned char *stole;`
The above statement declares `stole` as a pointer to `unsigned char` and contains garbage value, pointing to some random memory location.

`scanf("%s", stole);`
The above statement tries to store some string to memory pointed by `stole` which is being used by another program (atleast not allocated to your program for use). So, when `scanf` attempts to over-write this memory, you get `seg-fault`.

Try to allocate memory to `stole` as follows

`unsigned char stole[MAX_SIZE];`

or

```
unsigned char *stole = malloc((MAX_SIZE+1) * sizeof(char));
// +1 for null-terminating
```

---

[Dynamic String Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329909/dynamic-string-input-using-scanf)

Answer (score 1):

stole is a dangling pointer - you need to allocate some memory for it (e.g. malloc)

Comment: I don't see any need to use `malloc` here - I'd just say `unsigned char stole[SOMESIE];` where `SOMESIZE` is an appropriate size.

Comment: @Neil: sure, that's why I said *e.g.* - it's just one way to allocate some memory - a static allocation is also good.

Answer (score 1):

You have to supply the storage for `stole`, something like:

```
unsigned char stole[1024];
```

This will still give a segfault if the user enters a longer string than 1024 chars though, to fix this you can use:

```
scanf("%1023s", stole);
```

1023 is used instead of 1024 so that there's room for the string terminator.

Comment: Tnx for knowing the fix with scanf - i've never seen it before!