# Dynamic allocation with scanf()

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

My question is exactly the same as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329909/dynamic-string-input-using-scanf). That is, I'm trying to use `scanf()` to receive a string of indeterminate length, and I want `scanf()` to dynamically allocate memory for it.

However, in my situation, I am using VS2010. As far as I can see, MS's [scanf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y6s16x1) doesn't have an a or m modifier for when scanning for strings. Is there any way to do this (other than receiving input one character at a time)?

Comment: GNU C Library supports 'a' as an 'allocate memory' modifier; GNU C Library as of version 2.8 (the manual I happen to have) does not mention 'm' as a modifier.  Is that another addition since 2.8?

Comment: My manpages from 2008-07-12, version 3.23, mentions both. the `m` modifier is an replacement for the GNU extension `a` as it collides with the c99 modifier `a` which matches floats.

Comment: @Frank: time to download an update...thanks.  That's occasionally another disadvantage of non-standard extensions - the standard changes the meaning of the non-standard by standardizing it.

Comment: Well, I might need a new copy myself. I did not know that mine were so old, I guesses that nobody is refreshing the manpages in the Ubuntu repos, there is lots of outdated software both there and in the Debian repos... Why not have a system that automatically updates the repos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `scanf` you could just allocate a large enough buffer to hold any possible value, say 1024 bytes, then use a maximum field width specifier of 1024.

The `m` and `a` are specific non-standard GNU extensions, so thats why Microsofts compiler does not support them. One could wish that visual studio did.

Here is an example using `scanf` to read settings, and just print them back out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int
main( int argc, char **argv )
{   // usage ./a.out < settings.conf

    char *varname;
    int value, r, run = 1;

    varname = malloc( 1024 );

    // clear errno
    errno = 0;

    while( run )
    {   // match any number of "variable = #number" and do some "processing"

        // the 1024 here is the maximum field width specifier.
        r = scanf ( "%1024s = %d", varname, &value );
        if( r == 2 )
        {   // matched both string and number
            printf( " Variable %s is set to %d \n", varname, value );
        } else {
            // it did not, either there was an error in which case errno was
            // set or we are out of variables to match
            if( errno != 0 )
            {   // an error has ocurred.
                perror("scanf");
            }
            run = 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is an example `settings.conf`

```
cake = 5
three = 3
answertolifeuniverseandeverything = 42
charcoal = -12
```

You can read more about [`scanf` on the manpages](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/scanf.3.html).

And you can of course use `getline()`, and after that parse character after character.

If you would go into a little more what you are trying to achieve you could maybe get an better answer.

Comment: I would explain how to write a field width specifier, since OP is likely not to know and just to ignore the advice, creating a buffer overflow vulnerability...

Comment: Right, I probably should. But what does OP stand for?

Answer (score 4):

Standard versions of `scanf()` do not allocate memory for any of the variables it reads into.

If you've been hoodwinked into using a non-standard extension in some version of `scanf()`, you've just had your first lesson in how to write portable code - do not use non-standard extensions.  You can nuance that to say "Do not use extensions that are not available on all the platforms of interest to you", but realize that the set of platforms may change over time.

Comment: +1 for pointing out how relying on non-portable extensions has bit the OP.

Comment: The `m` modifier for s/c/[ in scanf has been part of the POSIX standard since at least 2001.  So its availble pretty much everywhere execpt on Microsoft

Comment: It's still not available on macOS X.

Answer (score 2):

Must you absolutely use `scanf` ? Aren't `std::string s; std::cin >> s;` or `getline( std::cin, s );` an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think, in real world, one need to have some maximum limit on length of user input.

Then you may read the whole line with something like `getline()`. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/

Note that, if you want multiple input from user, you don't need to have separate `char` arrays for each of them. You can have one big buffer, e.g. `char buffer[2048]`, for using with `getline()`, and copy the contents to a suitably allocated (and named) variable, e.g. something like `char * name = strdup( buffer )`.

Comment: It is probably better to let `getline()` allocate a buffer for you, if the buffer is not big enough then `getline()` will make it big enough.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `scanf` for reading strings. It probably doesn't even do what you think it does; `%s` reads only up until the next whitespace.

Comment: Don't be like that, your "answer" is not helpful. This guy does probably not have the man pages lying around and is asking for how he should do - not how he should **not**.

Comment: @Frank: I thought the point about `%s` and whitespace was a rather astute observation!

Comment: Yes, you are right, but maybe the guy know that %s does only read up to the next whitespace like std::cin does. High might have some code that has previously compiled on a *nix/GNU system before and tries to get it running on his vc10.

It would be easier if we/he had some existing code to work on/show.

Comment: My first sentence stands alone; the second is just extra commentary.