# How to Allocate Memory to a Pointer for Entered Input (in 'C')

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, input

I'm working on an assembler for a hypothetical machine (the SMAC-0 machine) and need some help with memory allocation.

I'll be getting and tokenizing strings from a given file and will save these tokens in pointers.

Here's a code snippet:

```
tokenCount = sscanf(buffer,"%s %s %s %s", tokenOne, tokenTwo, tokenThree, tokenFour);
```

where `tokenCount` is an integer, `buffer` is the temporary buffer that stores the line taken from the input file, and `tokenOne`, `tokenTwo`, `tokenThree`, and `tokenFour` are character pointers.

The strings accepted from the file can have one to four words:

> Example:

```
            READ    N
    N:      DS      1
    SUM:    DS      1
    LOOP:   MOVER   AREG    N
            ADD     AREG    N
            COMP    AREG    ='5'
            BC      LE      LOOP
            MOVEM   AREG    SUM
            PRINT   SUM
            STOP
```

My queries are:

How can I find out how large the token is and thus know how to allocate memory for the respective token pointer?

(That question also applies to the `buffer` pointer, since the labels (e.g. `LOOP`, `N`, `SUM`) can be of variable sizes.)

How can I, using `scanf()` or other input functions like `gets()`, do the same?

Comment: make the buffers for the tokens the same size as the input buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your token buffers large enough. To be on the safe side, it's a good idea to make all of them as large as the input buffer itself. See this this thread [How to prevent scanf causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c) for more information.

If you're using the GNU compiler, you can make use a extension which can dynamically allocate buffers on your behalf. Check out [Dynamic allocation with scanf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911547/dynamic-allocation-with-scanf)

### EXAMPLES:

**Using predefined buffers for the scanned tokens:**

Note all tokens have the same size as the input buffer:

```
/* sscanf-test.c */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  FILE *file = fopen("sample.txt", "r");
  const int BufferSize=256;
  char buffer[BufferSize];
  char tokenOne[BufferSize];
  char tokenTwo[BufferSize];
  char tokenThree[BufferSize];
  char tokenFour[BufferSize];

  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL)
  {
    tokenOne[0]='\0';
    tokenTwo[0]='\0';
    tokenThree[0]='\0';
    tokenFour[0]='\0';
    int tokenCount = sscanf(buffer, "%s %s %s %s", tokenOne, tokenTwo, tokenThree, tokenFour);
    printf("scanned %d tokens   1:%s 2:%s 3:%s 4:%s\n", tokenCount, tokenOne, tokenTwo, tokenThree, tokenFour);
  }

  fclose(file);
  return 0;
}
```

The program produces the following output (I cleaned up the formatting a little bit to improve readability):

```
gcc sscanf-test.c -o sscanf-test
./sscanf-test 
scanned 2 tokens   1:READ   2:N    3:     4: 
scanned 3 tokens   1:N:    2:DS    3:1    4: 
scanned 3 tokens   1:SUM:  2:DS    3:1    4: 
scanned 4 tokens   1:LOOP: 2:MOVER 3:AREG 4:N 
scanned 3 tokens   1:ADD   2:AREG  3:N    4: 
scanned 3 tokens   1:COMP  2:AREG  3:='5' 4: 
scanned 3 tokens   1:BC    2:LE    3:LOOP 4: 
scanned 3 tokens   1:MOVEM 2:AREG  3:SUM  4: 
scanned 2 tokens   1:PRINT 2:SUM   3:     4: 
scanned 1 tokens   1:STOP  2:      3:     4:
```

If you want to store the scanned tokens for later processing, you'll have to copy them somewhere else in the while-loop. You can use the function `strlen` to get the size of the token (excluding the trailing string terminator '\0').

**Using dynamic memory allocation for tokens:**

Like I said, you could also let scanf allocate buffers for you dynamically. The [scanf(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/scanf.3.html) man page states that you can use GNU extensions 'a' or 'm' to do that. Specifically it says:

> An optional 'a' character.  This is used with string conversions, and
>   relieves the caller of the need to allocate a corresponding buffer to 
>   hold the input: instead, scanf() allocates a buffer of sufficient
>   size,  and assigns the address of this buffer to the corresponding
>   pointer  argument, which should be a pointer to a char * variable
>   (this variable  does not need to be initialized before the call).  The
>   caller should  subsequently free(3) this buffer when it is no longer
>   required.  This  is a GNU extension; C99 employs the 'a' character as
>   a conversion  specifier (and it can also be used as such in the GNU
>   implementation)

I couldn't get scanf to work using the 'a' modifier. However, there's also the 'm' modifier which does the same thing (and more):

> Since version 2.7, glibc also provides the m modifier for the same
>   purpose as  the a modifier.  The m modifier has the following
>   advantages:
>
> - It may also be applied to %c conversion specifiers (e.g., %3mc).
> - It avoids ambiguity with respect to the %a floating-point
>     conversion  specifier (and is unaffected by gcc -std=c99 etc.)
> - It is specified in the upcoming revision of the POSIX.1 standard.

```
/* sscanf-alloc.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  FILE *file = fopen("sample.txt", "r");
  const int BufferSize=64;
  char buffer[BufferSize];
  char *tokenOne   = NULL;
  char *tokenTwo   = NULL;
  char *tokenThree = NULL;
  char *tokenFour  = NULL;

  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL)
  {
    // note: the '&', scanf requires pointers to pointer to allocate the buffers.
    int tokenCount = sscanf(buffer, "%ms %ms %ms %ms", &tokenOne, &tokenTwo, &tokenThree, &tokenFour);
    printf("scanned %d tokens   1:%s 2:%s 3:%s 4:%s\n", tokenCount, tokenOne, tokenTwo, tokenThree, tokenFour);

    // note: the memory has to be free'd to avoid leaks
    free(tokenOne);
    free(tokenTwo);
    free(tokenThree);
    free(tokenFour);
    tokenOne   = NULL;
    tokenTwo   = NULL;
    tokenThree = NULL;
    tokenFour  = NULL;
  }

  fclose(file);
  return 0;
}
```

```
gcc sscanf-alloc.c -o sscanf-alloc
./sscanf-alloc
scanned 2 tokens   1:READ  2:N      3:(null) 4:(null)
scanned 3 tokens   1:N:    2:DS     3:1      4:(null)
scanned 3 tokens   1:SUM:  2:DS     3:1      4:(null)
scanned 4 tokens   1:LOOP: 2:MOVER  3:AREG   4:N
scanned 3 tokens   1:ADD   2:AREG   3:N      4:(null)
scanned 3 tokens   1:COMP  2:AREG   3:='5'   4:(null)
scanned 3 tokens   1:BC    2:LE     3:LOOP   4:(null)
scanned 3 tokens   1:MOVEM 2:AREG   3:SUM    4:(null)
scanned 2 tokens   1:PRINT 2:SUM    3:(null) 4:(null)
scanned 1 tokens   1:STOP  2:(null) 3:(null) 4:(null)
```