# c fgets not waiting for input

Tags: c, fgets

I have 2 fgets into my code and both of them **aren't wait for input**...
This is an example of the first `fgets`...

```
printf("Insert path: ");
if(fgets(dirpath, BUFFGETS, stdin) == NULL){
    perror("fgets dir path");
    close(sockd);
}
```

and, as i've written before, also the next fgets is not waiting for my input :(
Before the first `fgets` i have 2 `scanf("%ms", &string);` (if this could be the trouble).

Comment: Any reason you can't just use `scanf` again?

Comment: What is the `'m'` doing in that `scanf()`?  Show us the real code (including the `scanf()` calls).

Comment: Also, look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6083941/12711 - it probably is related to your problem. Remember that the "%s" format in `scanf()` will stop reading at the first whitespace, leaving the whitespace in the stream. A newline is a whitespace character.

Comment: See this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329909/dynamic-string-input-using-scanfas) for %ms

Comment: @Arkadiy: do you have a link to docs for the `m` flag character?  I see the `a` flag (which is new to me) discussed in the GCC C lib docs, but the not the `m` flag. The SO question you link to simply says you should use `m` instead of `a` if using a new enough glibc, but there's no explanation of why or what's different.

Comment: Some discussion of the `m` flag for formatted input in glibc: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2007-09/msg01342.html  - I wonder why this hasn't made it into the GCC docs?

Comment: Here is the GNU doc on %as: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Dynamic-String-Input.html

Comment: @MichaelBurr: It's not in the GCC docs because it's not part of gcc; it's part of glibc.

Comment: @KeithThompson: fair enough, please forgive my imprecise wording. But it's not in the GNU C Library docs either (or more specifically: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/index.html).

Comment: Hassan: i cannot use scanf because it doesn't accept whitespace
MichaelBurr: 1) "http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2007-09/msg01342.html"
2) hey you've solved my problem :D love you!

Answer (score 1):

i think scanf does not read in the linebreak. You can try to read it in first with an additional fgets after scanf().

Comment: @Arkadiy: Don't use `"%s"` with `scanf`; it's prone to buffer overflows. It doesn't specify a maximum input length, so arbitrary input will overflow any possible buffer.

Comment: The important part is \n. %s really should be %ms as in the original code. Sorry about the confusion.