# snprintf and array of strings syntax

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct, printf

I have a struct that contains an array of strings but I'm lost regarding how to use it sometimes
For instance :

```
struct A
{
  char** b;
};

size_t two = 2;
struct A a = malloc(sizeof(struct A));
b = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * 2);
a->b[0] = "1";
snprintf(a->b[1], 4, "%d", two); //this line makes a mess
```

It works perfectly fine if I use snprintf for a variable that I define as char* type, but isn't a->b[1] a char* type itself ?
Why doesn't it work (if I use a printf on a->b[1], it displays the value but the program crashes when I do any malloc afterward) and what should I do to make it work ?

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
snprintf(a->b[1], 4, "%d", two);
```

dereferences `a->b[1]`, which has not been set. You cannot write into it. If you would like to write into `a->b[1]`, do it like that:

```
a->b[1] = malloc(4);
snprintf(a->b[1], 4, "%3d", two);
```

Now `a->b[1]` has a writeable block of memory of 4 bytes. `%3d` limits the output to three digits, in case variable `two` is set to a larger number.

Comment: Seems to work perfectly fine
But I'm kinda disapoint that I have to manually do a malloc and not just point to a new value returned by the function :(  
Thank you

Comment: @user3548298 Apart from [non-standard `%sa`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2330126/335858), there's no good option here :-(

Comment: The second argument to `snprintf()` limits the output. The `3` in `%3d` sets a different limit: the minimum field width.

Comment: Use `asprintf` if you want a function that allocates the memory for you.  Non-standard, but available on Windows, OSX, Linux, *BSD and many others.